# Visual Studio sql result table color

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to change look and font size of default sql results table in visual studio 2015 community?
I use dark theme and this looks simply awful.

[image: Screenshot]

edit:

also Color Theme Editor extension don't have such option

Answer (score 1):

Tools => Options => Environment => Font and Colors

At the top of the "Fonts and Colors" options group you will see "Show settings for:"

Select the "SQL Results - Grid" from the drop down list.

Then, change the colors of the SQL Results Grid as desired.